# mapping nested json in java data modal

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

> My API is has nested json am trying to map it out it in json so i can display it in fragments this is my json response from the server.
>   my main problem is mapping out the json objects to my data modal...
>   kindly assist where possible

---

```
[
  {
    "couponDate": "2019-07-14T11:34:09.482Z",
    "couponComment": "GooD LucK :)",
    "couponNumber": 1,
    "_id": "5d2b134149db640017f8fda4",
    "overUnder": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T11:34:09.472Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "jh",
          "league": "jhj"
        },
        "homeTeam": "jh",
        "awayTeam": "hj",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "Over0.5",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "overUnder",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b143749db640017f8fda6"
      },
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "overUnder",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30043b2bc800172f5f3f"
      }
    ],
    "threeWay": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "threeWay",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30083b2bc800172f5f40"
      }
    ],
    "doubleChance": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "doubleChance",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30003b2bc800172f5f3e"
      }
    ],
    "goalGoal": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "goalGoal",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b300c3b2bc800172f5f41"
      }
    ],
    "halfTime": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "halfTime",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30113b2bc800172f5f42"
      }
    ],
    "bookingPts": [

    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

This is my Java data modal:

```
public class gamesmodal {

    String couponComment;

    overs overUnder;
    String threeWay;
    String doubleChance;
    String goalGoal;
    String halfTime;
    String bookingPts;

    public String getTitle() {
       return couponComment;
    }

    public void setTitle(String couponComment) {
        this.couponComment = couponComment;
    }
 public class overs extends gamesmodal {
    String homeTeam;
    String awayTeam;
    String tip;

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    }

    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    public String getTip() {
        return tip;
    }

    public void setTip(String tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }
}



    public void setOverUnder(overs overUnder) {
        this.overUnder = overUnder;
    }


}
```

My logcat code is as follows:

> 2019-07-14 16:25:28.396 23946-23946/dvlp.lamseybets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: dvlp.lamseybets, PID: 23946
>       com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 137 path $[0].overUnder
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
>           at dvlp.lamseybets.matchResult$1.onResponse(matchResult.java:90)
>           at dvlp.lamseybets.matchResult$1.onResponse(matchResult.java:82)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 137 path $[0].overUnder
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129) 
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220) 
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
>           at dvlp.lamseybets.matchResult$1.onResponse(matchResult.java:90) 
>           at dvlp.lamseybets.matchResult$1.onResponse(matchResult.java:82) 
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83) 
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)  2019-07-14 16:25:29.993 23946-23957/dvlp.lamseybets I/art: Enter while loop.

so have changed the data modal  to this :

```
import java.util.List;

public class datamodal {

private List<overUnder> overUnder = null;
String couponComment;
private List<threeWay> threeWay = null;
private List<DoubleChance> doubleChance = null;
private List<HalfTime> halfTime = null;
private List<GoalGoal> goalGoal = null;


public String getCouponComment() {
    return couponComment;
}

public void setCouponComment(String couponComment) {
    this.couponComment = couponComment;
}

public List<overUnder> getOverUnder() {
    return overUnder;
}

public void setOverUnder(List<overUnder> overUnder) {

    this.overUnder = overUnder;
}

public List<DoubleChance> getDoubleChance() {
    return doubleChance;
}

public void setDoubleChance(List<DoubleChance> doubleChance) {
    this.doubleChance = doubleChance;
}

public List<HalfTime> getHalfTime() {
    return halfTime;
}

public void setHalfTime(List<HalfTime> halfTime) {
    this.halfTime = halfTime;
}

public List<GoalGoal> getGoalGoal() {
    return goalGoal;
}

public void setGoalGoal(List<GoalGoal> goalGoal) {
    this.goalGoal = goalGoal;
}

public List<threeWay> getThreeWay() {
    return threeWay;
}

public void setThreeWay(List<threeWay> threeWay) {
    this.threeWay = threeWay;
}
```

}

and i need the json responses to be displayed here

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class matchResult extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = matchResult.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String URL = "my url is here";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<datamodel> movieList;
    private StoreAdapter mAdapter;

    public matchResult() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public List<datamodel> datamodel() {
        return datamodel();
    }

    public static matchResult newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        matchResult fragment = new matchResult();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_match_result, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new StoreAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);



        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        fetchStoreItems();

        return view;
    }

    private void fetchStoreItems() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Couldn't fetch the store items! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        List<datamodel> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<datamodel>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        movieList.clear();
                        movieList.addAll(items);

                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error in getting json
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }


    class StoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private List<datamodel> movieList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView name, price;
            public ImageView thumbnail;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                name = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            }
        }

        public StoreAdapter(Context context, List<datamodel> movieList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.movieList = movieList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final datamodel movie = movieList.get(position);

            holder.name.setText((CharSequence) movie.getHomeTeam());
            holder.price.setText((CharSequence) movie.getAwayTeam());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return movieList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the logcat error clearly says `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 137 path $[0].overUnder`

so try this

In gamesmodal

```
private List<OverUnder> overUnder = null;

public List<OverUnder> getOverUnder() {
return overUnder;
}

public void setOverUnder(List<OverUnder> overUnder) {
this.overUnder = overUnder;
}
```

and OverUnder class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OverUnder {

    @SerializedName("betDate")
    @Expose
    private String betDate;
    @SerializedName("competition")
    @Expose
    private Competition competition;
    @SerializedName("homeTeam")
    @Expose
    private String homeTeam;
    @SerializedName("awayTeam")
    @Expose
    private String awayTeam;
    @SerializedName("gameStarted")
    @Expose
    private Boolean gameStarted;
    @SerializedName("gameFinished")
    @Expose
    private Boolean gameFinished;
    @SerializedName("homeHalfTimeScore")
    @Expose
    private Integer homeHalfTimeScore;
    @SerializedName("awayHalfTimeScore")
    @Expose
    private Integer awayHalfTimeScore;
    @SerializedName("homeScore")
    @Expose
    private Integer homeScore;
    @SerializedName("awayScore")
    @Expose
    private Integer awayScore;
    @SerializedName("tip")
    @Expose
    private String tip;
    @SerializedName("risk")
    @Expose
    private Integer risk;
    @SerializedName("tipResult")
    @Expose
    private String tipResult;
    @SerializedName("betCategory")
    @Expose
    private String betCategory;
    @SerializedName("tipper")
    @Expose
    private String tipper;
    @SerializedName("_id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    public String getBetDate() {
        return betDate;
    }

    public void setBetDate(String betDate) {
        this.betDate = betDate;
    }

    public Competition getCompetition() {
        return competition;
    }

    public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
        this.competition = competition;
    }

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    }

    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    public Boolean getGameStarted() {
        return gameStarted;
    }

    public void setGameStarted(Boolean gameStarted) {
        this.gameStarted = gameStarted;
    }

    public Boolean getGameFinished() {
        return gameFinished;
    }

    public void setGameFinished(Boolean gameFinished) {
        this.gameFinished = gameFinished;
    }

    public Integer getHomeHalfTimeScore() {
        return homeHalfTimeScore;
    }

    public void setHomeHalfTimeScore(Integer homeHalfTimeScore) {
        this.homeHalfTimeScore = homeHalfTimeScore;
    }

    public Integer getAwayHalfTimeScore() {
        return awayHalfTimeScore;
    }

    public void setAwayHalfTimeScore(Integer awayHalfTimeScore) {
        this.awayHalfTimeScore = awayHalfTimeScore;
    }

    public Integer getHomeScore() {
        return homeScore;
    }

    public void setHomeScore(Integer homeScore) {
        this.homeScore = homeScore;
    }

    public Integer getAwayScore() {
        return awayScore;
    }

    public void setAwayScore(Integer awayScore) {
        this.awayScore = awayScore;
    }

    public String getTip() {
        return tip;
    }

    public void setTip(String tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }

    public Integer getRisk() {
        return risk;
    }

    public void setRisk(Integer risk) {
        this.risk = risk;
    }

    public String getTipResult() {
        return tipResult;
    }

    public void setTipResult(String tipResult) {
        this.tipResult = tipResult;
    }

    public String getBetCategory() {
        return betCategory;
    }

    public void setBetCategory(String betCategory) {
        this.betCategory = betCategory;
    }

    public String getTipper() {
        return tipper;
    }

    public void setTipper(String tipper) {
        this.tipper = tipper;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Tip:
Parsing JSON is cumbersome and error-prone process if we do it manually. You can use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to parse your JSON for you within seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: @SAMNJORmtv Hey just go to that site and paste your JSON there. It will generate all your Model classes for you. It will not be wise if I post all model files here.

Answer (score 0):

You have some String objects expected:

```
    String threeWay;
    String doubleChance;
    String goalGoal;
    String halfTime;
    String bookingPts
```

But your JSON says that all of them are arrays.